# Multiple file upload in different fields

Tags: php, html, upload

I'm having troubles uploading a bunch of files from a form. I need to make the input fields separately, my form is something like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="form" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="file" name="upload[]" >
  <input type="file" name="upload[]" >
  ...(more inputs)
  <input type="file" name="upload[]" >

  <button id="submit-button">Upload</button>

</form>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.9 for this project for anything else but this upload, I can't seem to find anything that suits what I'm trying to do. I found a lot of multiple input stuff, but in that way I can't differenciate every file from one another, and I need to so save the url of every file to the right column in my DB.

I've used some of the code I've found on other similar questions but they doesn't seem to work. I've tried this one now :

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
foreach ((array)$_FILES['upload']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
    if ($_FILES['upload']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }          
    if ($_FILES['upload']['error'][$f] == 0) {             
        if ($_FILES['upload']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
            $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
        }
    }
}
}
```

I just get plain nothing, and the file I'm trying to upload doesn't show up on the server. I've checked with php_info() and it seems that the upload is enabled, and since I'm uploading a .pdf with just "Test" written on it about 7kb, I think the size is not the problem here.

I hope you guys can help me out, thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've removed the (array) casting and I have the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in path_of_file

Comment: why are you typcasting this? `(array)$_FILES['upload']['name']` its already an array

Comment: Are errors enabled? What errors do you get? Check your logs or make sure display_errors is on.

Comment: The original code was without it, I've seen some comments that were reporting something similar to my issue and I thought I might give it a try and see if that was the problem.

Comment: Make an output if your if-clausel doesn't turn out to be true.

Comment: Turns out it gets through the first "if" then it seems to ignore the foreach and goes straight to the end, uploading nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing very important element in this which is `enctype`.

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

Use this in your form tag and check again.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="form" name="form">
```

-> For your error, use the following code (updated) to upload multiple images

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files

foreach ($_FILES['username']['name'] as $f => $name) {

    $path = 'uploads'; //path of directory

    if ($_FILES['username']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    } else {
        if ($_FILES['username']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else {
            // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            //$name_of_file = $_FILES['username']['name'][$f];
            $temp_name = $_FILES['username']['tmp_name'][$f]; //[$count];
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$path/"."$name");
            $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still having the same error with that. But thanks anyway, I've added the element now!